# Prevent user to upload file using AD Group Policy

Tags: security, file-upload, active-directory, privacy

Is it possible to block file upload using group policy?

I do not want that users can upload file sites in any network using entreprise devices, so I think here comes local group policy.

I think this is hard task, but I need help, if you know solution. Other solutions are also open.

Thanks